# Mark usercontrol as obsolete

Tags: asp.net

We have a asp.net framework which is used by different teams.
In our framework we have an email user control which must be placed obsolete. The control has been rewritten as webcontrol.

Can I make the usercontrol obsolete?
I tried putting the obsolete attribute on the class name itself

```
<Obsolete("This usercontrol is obsolte. Use the web control AtaMail")> _
Partial Public Class UCAtaMail
   Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl
   ...
```

But this doesn't show with the teams when they reference the control on their aspx page.
Maybe there are other solutions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the backend code (.cs file) of the usercontrol.

[And here is how to mark something as obsolete in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664623%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)